# Grails 3.1.8 controller

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

I'm converting a grails 2.4.4 app to 3.1.8. 
In some of my controller methods sometimes (based on what happened in the service call) I'll just set a message in the flash and nothing else, this was fine in 2.4.4, the screen would be re-rendered with the flash message but in 3.1.8 nothing is rendered at all, the screen in totally blank. 
Seemingly if I add a statement after setting the message in the flash the screen is rendered, the statement can be anything e.g. println 'hello' or return or new ModelAndView(). 
Example below:

```
def index() { 
def res = myService.whatever() 
if (res) { 
    [res: res] 
} 
else { 
    flash.message = message( code: 'no.res' )  // if we get here nothing is rendered
}
}
```

Is this a change to grails 3 or am I missing something somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
def index() { 
    def res = myService.whatever() 

    [res: res]
}
```

Then in the index.gsp view

```
<g:if test="${res}">
    <!-- cool thing goes here -->
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <g:message code="no.res"/>
</g:else>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm not missing a section of the screen though, it's the whole page that's blank, and if I did implement the above I'd have to change around 100 gsp's. It's odd that when initially landing on e.g. index the screen renders fine but after that when a button is pressed and the screen is re-rendered unless I return something nothing is rendered. So far I've gone through my controllers and stuck a [:] to get things going.

Comment: I understand. About I'd have to change around 100 gsp's - I've been in the same situation. But sometimes that is the better option. Of course it totally depends on your case