# Grails upgrade path from 1.3.7 to 3.2.6

Tags: grails

I have a Grails application currently running on Grails 1.3.7.  I want to upgrade all the way to 3.2.6.

What would be the optimal path to do this?  Should I just go straight to 3.2.6 and then try to get dependencies and compilation errors straight?  Should I upgrade to 2.0 or 2.5.6 first, then go to 3.2.6?  I feel like smaller steps might be easier, but then it seems like it would be harder to find the proper plugin versions to go along with the Grails version.  I'm looking for the route that will require the least change and generate the least friction.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  I am working on going straight to 3.2.6 now.  It's definitely a daunting process, but it feels like it is going better than when I first started trying to go to 2.5.6.

Answer (score 4):

> What would be the optimal path to do this? Should I just go straight
>   to 3.2.6 and then try to get dependencies and compilation errors
>   straight? Should I upgrade to 2.0 or 2.5.6 first, then go to 3.2.6?

At OCI we have done many many of these upgrades since we released 3.0 over 2 years ago.  I advocate for skipping the 2.5.x step in almost all cases.  Doing the 2.5.x upgrade will require some work that will be undone when you upgrade to 3.2.x and there is no real benefit to paying that additional price.  The 2.5.x upgrade will be easier, but doesn't really buy you anything and you will have to take on the 3.x upgrade after that anyway, so just skip the intermediary step unless you have some specific compelling reason to include it (at this point, almost no apps have a valid justification for including that intermediary 2.5.x step).

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't gone from Grails 1.x to 3.x but have gone from 2.x to 3.x.

I would have thought you'd be better off going straight to 3 but don't expect it to be easy.

I would say make sure all the plugins you currently use have been ported to [Grails 3](https://grails.org/plugins.html) & if not make plans to either do it yourself or rewrite code to fit.
FWIW I documented my upgrade process [here](https://gist.github.com/leadtrip/ef8b02a693b49ba3f6ca9cd60eea4e66).

Comment: there are some things in that doc that are incorrect.  For example, we didn't change things such that controller actions have to return something.  They don't.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I don't understand how you can say they are incorrect, they are my findings from a real world upgrade, they may not be what you expected but they happened during my upgrade, I wish you'd have been around to help with my one and only ever question on stackoverflow at the time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170916/grails-3-1-8-controller

Comment: "I don't understand how you can say they are incorrect" - I can say they are incorrect because some of them are.  For example, that doc says that controller methods now have to return a value.  They don't.

Answer (score 0):

Remember there is no `config.groovy` in Grails 3. All your configuration you need to manage on `application.yml`. You need to manage your repositories and plugins on `build.gradle`
Study this document first http://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/guide/upgrading.html

Then, have a look on it [Grails Version Update](https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/mathifonseca/version-update)